# WPF multiple filters not working on DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, collectionview

I have a DataGrid that is bound to a CollectionView *LogDataView* of type *LogData*. For each data in dataGrid, I have two filters, One for *LogType* and another for *LogDirection*.  My problem is If I apply direction filter (ex-RX), then in LogType Filter returns true for TX messages also. So now I see both RX and TX messages (ideally I should see only RX). 
I use button click to apply filters.

I have gone through [WPF multiple filters CollectionViewSource, first filter added works correctly, second filter added does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752591/wpf-multiple-filters-collectionviewsource-first-filter-added-works-correctly-s) but no help.
Please suggest.

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid Name="dgLogdata"  Margin="10" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ItemsSource="{Binding LogDataView}"
                                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" >                          
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="H" Binding="{Binding HData}" FontFamily="Arial"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Raw"   Binding="{Binding Hex}" FontFamily="Arial"/>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {           
            private string _content;
            private ObservableCollection<LogData> _logDataOC { get; set; }

            private byte _LogDir    = (byte)LogDirEnum.ELogDir_NONE; 
            private byte _LogLevel= (byte)LogTypeEnum.ELogType_NONE;
            public string Header { get; set; }


            public byte ELogDir
            {
                get { return _LogDir; }
                set { _LogDir = value; }
            }
            public byte ELogLevel
            {
                get { return _LogLevel; }
                set { _LogLevel = value; }
            }
            public Item()
            {
                LogDataOC = new ObservableCollection<LogData>();

                //add the filters
                var vLogDirFilter = new Predicate<object>(o => LogDirFilter(o as LogData));
                LogDataView.Filter += vLogDirFilter;

                var vLogLevelFilter = new Predicate<object>(o => LogLevelFiler(o as LogData));
                LogDataView.Filter += vLogLevelFilter;
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                var handler = PropertyChanged;
                handler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

            public ObservableCollection<LogData> LogDataOC
            {
                get { return _logDataOC; }
                set
                {
                    _logDataOC = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("LogDataOC");
                }
            }           

            public ICollectionView LogDataView => CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(LogDataOC);

            /**********************************Filter properties********************************/

            /*****LOG DIRECTION FILTER*****/
            private bool LogDirFilter(LogData m)
            {
                if (_LogDir == (byte)LogDirEnum.ELogDir_NONE)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else if (_LogDir == m.LogDir)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            /*******LOG LEVEL FILTER*******/
            bool LogLevelFiler(GUILogData m)
            {
                if (_LogLevel == (byte)LogLevelEnum.ELogLevel_NONE)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else if (_LogLevel == m.LogLevel)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }


        }
```

**Button Click**

```
        private void BtnRX_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Item item = null;
            //get the current tab
            if (ItemMap.ContainsKey(tabControl1.SelectedIndex))
            {
                item = ItemMap[tabControl1.SelectedIndex];
            }

            if (item != null)
            {
                //set the direction here to filter
                item.ELogDir = (byte)LogDirEnum.ELogDir_RX;
                item.LogDataView.Refresh();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Filters are applied in the order they are added*. You need to sync the two filters. Maybe using a variable.

```
            private bool bLogDirFilter = true;
            private bool bLogLevelFilter = true;
```

filter function

```
private bool LogDirFilter(GUILogData m)
            {
                if (ELogDir == (byte)LogDirEnum.ELogDir_NONE)
                {
                    bLogDirFilter = true;
                    return true;
                }
                else if (ELogDir == m.LogDir)
                {
                    bLogDirFilter = true;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    bLogDirFilter = false;
                    return false;
                }
            }

            /*******LOG LEVEL FILTER*******/
            bool LogLevelFiler(GUILogData m)
            {
                if (bLogDirFilter && (ELogLevel == (byte)LogLevelEnum.ELogLevel_NONE))
                {
                    bLogLevelFilter = true;
                    return true;
                }
                else if (bLogDirFilter && (ELogLevel == m.LogLevel))
                {
                    bLogLevelFilter = true;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    bLogLevelFilter = false;
                    return false;
                }
            }
```